# Which blogs should I follow to learn TDD?

Tags: tdd

I am trying to learn how to employ Test Driven Development into my coding practices. Are there any blogs out there that anyone can recommend that regularly posts information about using TDD?

Comment: If this question weren't asking for off-site resources which is off-topic on Stack Exchange network, I would recommend you to ask this question on http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ which is primarily intended for questions about testing. So if you'll have questions about testing in the future, you'll might get better help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are prepared to buy a book Roy Osherove's book 'The Art of Unit Testing' is a great read when starting out with TDD.
Roy also has a blog [here](http://osherove.com/blog/).
Uncle Bob has some great blog posts [here](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob).

A colleague of mine has some very clear concise blog articles on TDD [here](http://developmentthoughts.wordpress.com/).

If you don't know what a code kata is have a look at at the kata catalogue at http://codingdojo.org/.  Code kata's are a great way to practice TDD.

I have written a blog post on solving the FizzBuzz kata, it's a very simple kata, but in my post my aim is to demonstrate how to go about doing TDD test first.  You can see the blog post [here](http://chilliandrew.blogspot.com/2013/12/tdd-so-whats-this-test-first-thing.html).

There are also some great TDD videos up on PluralSight although you would need to pay for these.

Learning to do TDD is a journey and can be pretty frustrating to get right to start with, but if you do get it right the rewards are massive so I would suggest giving it a real go.

Answer (score 2):

Bob Martin blogs here now - well worth following: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/archive.html

Also Jason Gorman: http://codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/

and the Growing Object Oriented Software group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/growing-object-oriented-software